# UIScrollView doesn't scroll even though nearly identical others do in same view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a view controller's view laid out in IB, and in particular I have three views that all have identical layout constraints concerning their frames and have all been set to `UIScrollView`. Their content is different (I fade in one view and then another as the user navigates through a progression). I set all three of these views to `UIScrollView` and then I dropped the following code into my `.m` file in `viewWillAppear`:

```
NSArray <UIScrollView *> *viewsForScrolling = @[view1, view2, view3];
for (UIScrollView *smallView in viewsForScrolling) {
    NSLog(@"here is the class %@", [smallView class]);
    smallView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    smallView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(smallView.frame.size.width, smallView.frame.size.height*1.4);
    smallView.delegate = self;
}
```

This is doing the trick beautifully with `view1` and `view3` but `view2` **does not scroll**. I have verified that they all have the same class, `UIScrollView` and that they are all wired to the instance variable I expected.

The **principal difference** between `view2` and `view1`, `view3` is that `view 2` **contains a UITableView for which scrolling is not enabled.** That's the only difference I can figure out as compared to the other views.

I have also tried the following:

- for `view2` I log the value of `scrollingEnabled` and `userInteractionEnabed` and these are both `YES` as I would desire
- I tried reordering the views in their z components within IB. This made no difference.
- I tried programmatically resizing the `contentSize` of `view2` again outside the loop above thinking maybe it was 'not enough' but this was not the case
- I verified that `scrollViewDidScroll` is not running again when `view2` is visible and the other views are not visible.
- I changed the background color of `view2` to make sure it was as big as I thought it was and that I was indeed touching it when I tried to scroll. No dice.
- Per the suggestion below, I tried disabling user interaction for the tableview contained in `view2`. The interaction was disabled but this did not result in scrolling.
- Removing the scroll view entirely from `view2` **does** enable scrolling in `view2` but that's not really a solution.

  **I could really use another set of eyes and additional suggestions as to what to troubleshoot. Thank you.**

Comment: You should try disabling user interaction for the table view. This will probably make the scroll view work as you expect. From there you can look at different solutions for re-enabling user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your viewController conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol, set it as delegate for view2 and tableview, and implement the following protocol method this way:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```